# OpenGL/GLM: Converting a NDC to world coordinates, to select objects with mouse?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, 3d, glm-math

My goal is to implement a way of selecting objects in a scene by mouse, for a game.  My theory is that all I need do is ask for the points `(mouseX, mouseY, -1)` and `(mouseX, mouseY, 1)` in Native Device Coordinates, 'un'transform them through the view matrix first (so both points still overlap from the camera's perspective, then 'un'transform them through the perspective matrix so I get points I can use with a simple raycast against model bounding boxes.  (I might have mixed up the order of 'un'transformations, correct me if I'm wrong!)

I believe I can convert the opposite way around, from the perspective scene to NDC, using this algorithm (I am still writing the test scene, so I haven't had a chance to see if this is correct though)

```
glm::vec3 Camera::convertPerspectivePointToDeviceCoordinates(glm::vec3 worldPoint){
    glm::vec4 vector = m_finalViewTransform * glm::vec4(worldPoint, 1.0f);
    vector.x /= vector.w;
    vector.y /= vector.w;
    vector.z /= vector.w;
    return glm::vec3(vector.x, vector.y, vector.z);
}
```

But to do the reverse is puzzling me... how would one do that?  Any answer that takes advantage of glm for matrice math would be appreciated, but I can work from just math okay as well.

Also, I'm using OpenGL without the fixed pipeline, if that changes anything.  I have the matrices for view and projection stored if needed

Comment: Just use the inverted transformation matrix. `glm::inverse(m_finalViewTransform)`. Maybe checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692988/opengl-math-projecting-screen-space-to-world-space-coords-solved